# How define colours in python by using numpy array?

Tags: python

I read something like the below:

```
black = np.array([0, 0, 0, 255])
white = np.array([255, 255, 255, 255])
yellow = np.array([255, 255, 0, 255])
red = np.array([255, 0, 0, 255]) 
blue = np.array([0, 0, 255, 255])
```

what are these values? they are static or defined based on problem?

Comment: ussually it deppends on problems, but the most common ways to define colors is using RGB or RGBA encodingds. Here you writed RGBA (Red, Green, Blue, Transparency) where 0 means 0 intensity in that color and 255 the max one (max number in 8bits) for example [0,0,0,255] means black without trasparency. and  [255,255,255,255] is white. [255,0,0,255] red and so

Comment: It's RGBA , has nothing to do with python or numpy

Answer (score 0):

That is not a feature of numpy but rather how the user chose to represent color as what is extremely likely the [RGBA color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model).